# Pi 4 cannot read 'sdcard'

Tags: pi-4, pi4-eeprom

I have a pi 4 I previously ran rasbian stretch headless on. After a while I could no longer connect to the pi so I left it in the corner for a few months until I got a mini hdmi converter.
This time I flashed raspberry pi OS bullseye but when it tries to boot it can't find the SD card. I know my card is working because it boots fine in the pi 3b. The picture below is the error I get. What could be the problem?[image]

Comment: "I have a pi 4 I previously ran rasbian stretch headless on." **IMPOSSIBLE** the Pi4 only ran on Buster.

Comment: perhaps the sd slot is damaged

Comment: Yes it was buster.